# Adding tag items into an nsmutable array correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

I am trying to add all of the cell.img.tag to my nsmutable array. However, I tried multiple ways of doing this such as for loop, but the result was incorrect each time. I need each individual tag added to the NSMutableArray. I will post my code below to give you an idea. Note: this is just to show what I am doing, this wasn't the method I tried to use to make this work.

```
  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    Cell *cell = (Cell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *string = [addressString valueForKey:@"number"];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    cell.img.tag = string.intValue;
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.img.tag]];
    return cell;
 }
```

Edit: When I used the for loop it will show all the tags, but just ended up creating multiple arrays with same value in each array repeated multiple times like so.
(1,1,1)(2,2,2).

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Each time the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function is called you're basically destroying the array and creating a new empty one.

Move that line somewhere else in your code (in the `init` method, for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the code.  The first is the array allocation each time the datasource fetches a cell.. I suspect this is not really in your implementation, since you say "this wasn't the method I tried to use to make this work."

The other problem, the reason you see the same object over and over is that the part of the model you fetch `NSString *string = [addressString valueForKey:@"number"];` is invariant with respect to the indexPath passed to the datasource.

Do you have an array of addresses?  This would make more sense:

```
NSString *addressString = self.myArrayOfAddressesWichIsMyModel[indexPath.row];
NSString *string = [addressString valueForKey:@"number"];
```

Now string will change each time.  Re-examine your datasource method `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`  You're probably answering the count of some array.  That's the array that must be dereferenced by indexPath.row in your cellForItem method.